# Random number and alphabet with batch file

Tags: batch-file

I want make Random number and alphabet with batch. Print to * . text
Form of * . text is

```
SD=[Random number and alphabet]
DD=[Random number]
```

Please help me !!! Thanks for read

Comment: I'm uncertain about what you want. Do you want only one file or many? Are the file names related to the random [alpha]numeric characters? Can you give an example of what you're interested in?

Answer (score 0):

[How to use random in BATCH script?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5777400/how-to-use-random-in-batch-script)

gives a good hint to use random numbers, also setting the range.

with setting the range to 1-26 you can also chose a random letter by selecting the letter from a list by that generated number.

Comment: It is funny that you posted an answer when I don't even understand the question. How SD and DD variables should be used in your solution? Note that the OP does _not_ question "how to generate a random number or letter".

Comment: @Aacini you're right that OP does not even ask a question, but he write's, that he "want to make" (...) so i supposed that i cover at least one point. ^.^ i like it very much, when people try to get an answer by themselves, not like "this is my problem - now give me a solution!" :)

Comment: I think that is better to know what the request is before answer instead of trying to guess or post anything, unless your main interest is to get rep points! `;-)`

Comment: well yeah, you're right. Should i delete my supposed answer? :)

Comment: If you do so, you should also delete [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26804284/manage-shortcuts-arguments-for-nsis-createshortcut-method-via-cmake/26810662#26810662) where you said "i don't now anything about NSIS, but maybe this is a hint in the right direction", or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26827340/batch-file-variable-output/26827766#26827766), or [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26826961/creating-the-pppoe-internet-connection-using-batch-file/26827127#26827127), ...